# What's the sample size required to confirm that two treatments are identical?

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, statistical-power, descriptive-statistics, measurement-error

Goal: Determine if a machine is defective

Say I am going to give the same treatment to a group of people. I have a machine that will randomly split them into $2$ groups before giving the same treatment ($50\%$ chance of being in either group). Treatment has a known success rate of about $20\%$. So, chance of a successful treatment in either group is $0.2\cdot 0.5 = 10\%$.

I'm trying to test the machine for an unknown bias in how equally it administers treatment and how randomly it splits the people.

So if I have $100$ people. I would expect $50$ people to end up in each group and $10$ in each group to show successful treatment.

If I test fewer people, there is a higher chance of success rates' being different for the two samples due to chance and sample sizes being different. But with more people, the sizes of the two groups and the success rates for the two groups should approach the expected numbers **if** the machine is working properly.

How many people do I need to test to see if the success rates are different enough that I can conclude the machine is defective with $90\%$ certainty?

Should I use power analysis to determine the sample size needed to rule out effects greater than say $1\%$ relative difference? It seems a power analysis would dictate an infinite sample size to rule out an effect close to zero. Is there an assumption in power analysis that is violated when used in this situation?

Would I adapt some method like this?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair#Examples

Thank you.